# Powershell comparing two List with foreach

Tags: powershell, foreach, contains

I'm trying to compare two lists that I obtained with the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet.

I read about the `Compare-Object` cmdlet, but in this context I would prefer doing with a foreach because is useful to have access to the `$file` variable.

```
$StartingFolderPath = "C:\---\StartingFolder"
$EndingFolderPath = "C:\---\EndingFolder"


$AllStartingFiles = Get-ChildItem $StartingFolderPath 
$AllEndingFiles = Get-ChildItem $EndingFolderPath

Write-Host "First folder content:"$AllStartingFiles 
Write-Host "Second folder content:" $AllEndingFiles  


foreach($file in $AllEndingFiles){

    write-Host "Element :" $file.Name

    $result = $AllStartingFiles.Contains($file.Name)
    write-host $result

    if($AllStartingFiles.Contains($file.Name)){
    Write-Host  "You are here"
    Write-Host $file.Name
    }    
}
```

But it seems that I cannot pass the if control, `if($AllStartingFiles.Contains($file.Name))` which returns false.

OUTPUT

```
First folder content: 1_one.txt 2_two.txt 3_three.txt 5_five.txt
Second folder content: 1_one.txt 2_two.txt 3_three.txt 4_four.txt 5_five.txt 
6_six.txt
Element : 1_one.txt
False
Element : 2_two.txt
False
Element : 3_three.txt
False
Element : 4_four.txt
False
Element : 5_five.txt
False
Element : 6_six.txt
False
```

I've also tried with the `-Contains` operator, but without any luck.

Comment: Sorry, what's wrong with `Compare-Object`?

Comment: In my context I know that the EndingFolder always contains the StartingFolder's elements. So I don't really need to check the difference between the two list, but instead when I found the common elements, perform some operations on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't address the `Name` attribute during

```
$result = $AllStartingFiles.Contains($file.Name)
```

The correct way would be:

```
$result = $AllStartingFiles.Name.Contains($file.Name)
```

---

Never the less if only don't want to use `Compare-Object` because you are scared you'll lose the file attributes, this is not the case.

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $AllEndingFiles -DifferenceObject $AllStartingFiles -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject
```

This will give you all the files that appear in both lists and their attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a reason **not** to use compare-object:

```
> tree /F
├───first
│       1_one.txt
│       2_two.txt
│       3_three.txt
│       5_five.txt
│
└───second
        1_one.txt
        2_two.txt
        3_three.txt
        4_four.txt
        5_five.txt

> compare (gci .\first\) (gci .\second\)

InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
4_four.txt  =>
```

Comment: one would probably be what he stated that he wants to do other operations using the other properties of the object which is common between the two lists/arrays.